# Блок с картинкой HTML CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Нужно сделать что-то вроде кратких инфоблоков с возможностью голосовать и с сортировкой по рейтингу по типу как на картинке. Ковыряюсь уже 3 дня на WPress вручную реально запарилась. Может есть простой способ или плагин для этих целей?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://www.kunkalabs.com/mixitup-multifilter/

Comment: @E_K и что это такое?

Comment: @DaemonHK, плагин для сортировки

Comment: @E_K, а как сортировка относится к вопросу?